# Question on SDL Web 8.5 Hotfix numbering

Tags: web8.5, hotfixes

We have a question regarding the versioning of the CD hotfixes. 
For example, we have hotfix CD_8.5.0.3742, CD_8.5.0.3922 and CD_8.5.0.5099

All three hotfixes contain an updated version of the deployer microservice.

Now, my question is : is it safe to assume that the hotfix 8.5.0.5099 contains all fixes that were in the previous deployer microservice hotfixes as well ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid, your assumption wrong to clarify to understand, For Eg: Hotfix **CD_8.5.0.5099** last 4digit number it's not the release number it's Hotfix **CRQ** number (**CRQ-5099**), It will be explained detail in the Release notes.

Hence, With help of CRQ number we can't identify the latest Hotfix included or not, In the customer FTP **/software/_Hotfixes/Tridion & Web/Web 8.5**, you can able to sort by Last modified date column to identify the latest Hotfix releases CRQ.

Possibility latest updated Hotfix version should contain the previous fixes too If anything.

I would advise to raising to SDL support for clarification.

Comment: It looks like this is correct. We should check the latest date when a hotfix file is released. This seems to be mentioned as well on this page : https://gateway.sdl.com/apex/communityknowledge?articleName=000003582 - "So in Summary, if you have 2 hotfixes with the same jar files, always apply the latest released. "

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not safe to assume (as Velmurugan states)

When a hotfix includes previous hotfixes it will explicitly indicate this - if it doesn't then assume it does not include them.

Obviously, this means that a later hotfix *could* undo the goodness done by a previous one - and if there's some other *'cross-version'* dependency (such as a specific DLL expected but being overwritten to a function not rolled back in Anguilla) you could end up with an unstable system.

If you see the same assets being updated is different hotfixes then you should reach out to support.

The "Hotfix Rollup" is the one that is tested and supported as a 'collection' of latest hotfixes from SDL Support.

Also of interest could be the Alchemy Hotfix plugin as this makes some attempt to monitor specific files that are updated (although I don't know if you can run any sort of report of the data collected at this point).

Comment: Also to consider (thanks @harald-hoffelinck) is that the microservice hotfixes are coming in with *all* files at 100mb-200mb! Does that mean we're installing 2 hotfixes and should be testing more than just what we are fixing?